# x-editable popup not showing in ajax page loading

Tags: x-editable

x-editable popup not showing at all in ajax page load. I am retrieving page content within a table through AJAX and my requirement is to apply editable for each cell value. It works fine on first time page load but the editable popup is not working while the table data gets updated through AJAX. But overall functionality working fine.

Comment: Share code details

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself by just putting this line in your ajax page to initialize the popup as default.

**$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';**